# How many iPhone 6s plus can I bring from US to Malaysia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cellphones, regulations

I bought 3 iPhone 6s plus and I'm using iPhone 4s right now. I want to give iPhone to my mom and my GF. Can I hand carry all of them?

Comment: Is your question if it's allowed, or if you'll have to pay any customs/import duties, or something else?

Comment: Both of them please. I'm not sure if it is allowed to bring so many. and do I have to pay for any customs/import duties? I don't think I can put them into my big luggage which is not hand carry with me. Because I can't put electronic device in it right?

Comment: In some places they seem to be prohibiting anything with lithium  batteries in checked baggage. It's a good idea, IMO.  You should also worry about theft with $2-$3K worth of easily recognized stuff in three little pocket-sized  boxes.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter whether you transport goods in your carry-on or checked luggage. All of it is subject to possible declaration to customs officials. The [current form](http://www.bnm.gov.my/files/new_currency_declaration/en.custom.form.22.pdf) says that all gifts and souvenirs over 200 RM must be declared.

As of 9 October 2015, I'm unable to access the main website for [Malaysian customs](http://www.customs.gov.my) to try to find the amount of duty that might be levied.

Comment: Website is back up as of 10/10/2015, but I haven't been able to find the information (add en to the link to get to the English version).